# Proper way to clear a buffer in a different thread

Tags: java, concurrency

I am faced with this problem.
I have a processor class `Processor` that receives data from a client app, does a bunch of calculations and insert the result into a database.
I split the insert to DB to a different class `DataLayer`
To avoid blocking the thread, I made the `DataLayer` class doesn't insert into the database right away but instead add the results to a list `List<Result> buffer`.
Every hour, the `DataLayer` would take the buffer insert to the database and clear the buffer
Now I am sure I could run into a race condition when clearing the buffer.
What is the right way to do this to avoid any concurrency issues

code snippet:

```
public class Processor{
  
  private DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer();

  void accept(List<Data> data){
     //receive data from client app
     List<Result> results = calculateResults(data);
     saveResults(results)
  }

  List<Result> calculateResults(List<Data> data){

  void saveResults(List<Result> results){
     dataLayer.insertToDB(results);
  }

 }


public class DataLayer {

   private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

   private List<Result> buffer = new ArrayList<>();

   public DataLayer(){
      scheduleHourlyCheck();
   }

   void insertToDB(List<Result> results){
      this.buffer.add(results)
   }

   scheduleHourlyCheck(){
     taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
       jdbcTemplate.update(...)
       buffer.clear()   // ------> i am sure this shouldn't be done
     }, everyHour)
   }
}
```

My issue is this:
`buffer.clear()`

I am sure this could cause concurrency issues
what is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Is `Processor.accept` only called from one thread?

Comment: non, ```Processor.accept``` can be called from different threads

Answer (score 1):

The smallest change you need to make is wrap `ArrayList` with `Collections.synchronizedList`:

```
private List<String> buffer = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

This would be required even if you didn't periodically call `clear`.

This avoids two threads from accessing the list at the same time, whether they are both adding items or one is adding items and the other is clearing the list.

If you iterate on the list within `jdbcTemplate.update(...)` - that still needs to be synchronized externally:

```
synchronized (buffer) {
    jdbcTemplate.update(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So my understanding is in addition to the @akuzminykh response above, the buffer array list should be a synchronized list?

Comment: If there are uses of the `buffer` you haven't shown, using `Collections.synchronizedList` will ensure those thread-safe. Otherwise, you need to add `synchronized` blocks everywhere you use `buffer`. Note that either attempts to  add items to the list are blocked while the database updates run - if that's a problem you'll need a different approach

Comment: I see. Yes, having the ```buffer.add``` blocking the thread is an issue for me. In this particular case, i have the option to have all DB inserts at end of day, which is what i would do. But in general, how would one solve this?

Comment: You have threads that produce items and a thread that consumes them: a *queue* is more appropriate than a list for this use case, and there is a non-blocking queue implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html But adopting it may mean you have to rewrite code that assumes you are working on a List

Comment: Actually this is exactly what i needed. So now, I assume, there is no need for synchronized since the queue is thread-safe. So i should be able to safely iterate through the quue, insert and remove. Something like this: ```Iterator<Result> it = queue.iterator(); while(it.hasNext()){ results = queue.next(); jdbcTemplate.update(); queue.remove(results)}``` correct?

Comment: That probably works, assuming you never get duplicate Result objects. New items may get added while the iteration runs, before remove gets called. The usual idiom for processing a queue is to `poll` until there are no more items: `while ((result=queue.poll()) != null) update(result);`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that some inserts could be ignored. When you update the database with the current list (`jdbcTemplate.update(...)`) and clear it right after (`buffer.clear()`), any insert in between would be ignored because it would be instantly cleared away.

One way to solve that is to simply mark involved sections as `synchronized`:

```java
void insertToDB(List<Result> results){
    synchronized (buffer) {
        this.buffer.add(results)
    }
}
```

```java
scheduleHourlyCheck(){
    taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
        synchronized (buffer) {
            jdbcTemplate.update(...);
            buffer.clear();
        }
    }, everyHour)
}
```

If you want to avoid that the adders have to wait for all database-updates to finish (and you certainly do) then you can simply copy the list for the updates.

```java
scheduleHourlyCheck(){
    taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {
        List<Result> temp; 
        synchronized (buffer) {
            temp = new ArrayList<>(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
        jdbcTemplate.update(...); // but use temp here
    }, everyHour)
}
```

Now you've exactly what you've stated in the question: A synchronized mechanism that periodically updates your database.

Comment: Yes, this was something i was already concerned about (the fact that some inserts maybe ignored). How do i know when or not to use "synchronized"?

Comment: @Himura Well, this cannot be answered in a general way, there are just too many aspects. One way is to analyze the order in which the threads execute each statement like I did here. You can tell that updating the database with a set of updates and clearing those updates belong together; they should be *atomic*. Otherwise an addition in between could be ignored.